# Loop within STACK question in moodle using jsxgraph

Tags: loops, stack, moodle, jsxgraph

I am trying to create a moodle-STACK question with an interactive element via `jsxgraph`.

Within the `[[jsxgraph]]` ... `[[/jsxgraph]]` tags, I am plotting a curve with two databases, each with 6 elements.

Since I would like students to add error bars for both scales, I added a loop within the `jsxgraph-element`:

```js
var plot = function() {
  var j,  xr0, yr0, xr1, yr1, xr2, yr2, err1, err2;

    board.suspendUpdate();
    for (j=0; j<6;j++) {
      const v1 = Number(input1.Value());
      const v2 = Number(input2.Value());
      xr1 = dataX[j]-v1;
      yr1 = dataY[j]+v2;
      xr2 = dataX[j]+v1;
      yr2 = dataY[j]-v2;
      xr0 = dataX[j];
      yr0 = dataY[j];
      err1 = board.create('line',[[xr1,yr0],[xr2,yr0]],{straightFirst:false,straightLast:false, fixed:true});
      err2 = board.create('line', [[xr0,yr1],[xr0,yr2]],{straightFirst:false,straightLast:false, fixed:true});
      }
  };
```

Since the `jsxgraph` code is within the HTML-text field of the STACK-question in moodle, the `<` sign is converted to `&lt;` and now the loop cant be executed.

Is there a way to use a `<` sign within the HTML-field of moodle?  If not, how can I get past this problem?

I already wrote a running Javascript-Code that shows what I want to create within moodle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/Furfinator/3q8yk7hp/15/

Comment: Are you using the moodle plain text area editor?

Comment: I am using the Moodle HTML-text-editor. In addition, because moodle is changing the structure of the code after every saving process, I am pasting the clear jsxgraph code each time new.

Comment: The STACK community strongly advices to use the plain text editor. Would this be possible for you and do you have the problems there, too? One further possibility is to reverse the inequality and use the >-symbol.

Comment: That's the editor i am using. The problem was, that the setting "HTML entities" was set default to "false", after turning the setting to "true" it worked. But there is a new problem, since moodle does not want to run the function at all. When running the task the console calls ```xr01 is not defined```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo in the code which uses `xr01` instead of `xr1`?

Comment: Yes, i made a minimal example where i changed the variable xr1 to xr01. The exact Error which occurs is: ```preview.php?id=43903&courseid=27:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: xr01 is not defined
    at plot1 (preview.php?id=43903&courseid=27:49)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (preview.php?id=43903&courseid=27:45)```

Comment: Does the error also happen outside of STACK? Can you post a jsfiddle with the latest code?

Comment: Sure, but the actual jsfiddle code looks a bit different: https://jsfiddle.net/Furfinator/mhrw8zex/2/ Within the moodle question I tried to put the js-functions into script-tags within the HTML code of the question, but then the error occurs. When I try to put the function to the [[jsxgraph]] tags, the error "unexpected token ']' " within the functions occurs. In jsfiddle the task is perfectly running

Comment: I finally found a solution for the problem: you have to edit the task directly within the xml-file. In my case I have to insert the code outside of the <![CDATA[...]]> tags, then moodle doesn't change the entity of "<" and the code works!